# caching server bitmap image using universal image loader

Tags: android, caching, imageview, universal-image-loader

I'm developing a chatting application. When user press on "[Tap on image]", then ImageActivity launches and get the bitmap from the server then do some processing on bitmap and finally display it to user.

What I need to, If user already visited on that link then image should be displayed from cache. Any one has idea how to implement caching in an Activity that display's only one image using universal image loader.

Comment: store the image on sdcard with a unique name, look if the image is there => display, if not load from server?

Comment: It's not possible, as client require to store image on server rather than sdcard

Comment: @A.S. It's not possible as images are secure. We can't download the image that's the basic requirement from client.

Comment: You saying you can't download image but you looking for caching method to store image, i will post the class that keep images in cache by id you don't have to use universal image Loader but clear it to me first, (What you think about downloading and caching please specify what you looking for memory cache or file cache?)

Comment: @Ishrat, thanks for your reply. I found mistake on my code. Now It's caching... I will post the answer after refactoring the code.